# What is the function of Stream Id parameter in RTMP header?

Tags: java, rtmp, wowza

In wiki article on RTMP http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol one can find  the description of RTMP header. One of the params found inside is StreamId. StreamId is described as

> The 6 least significant bits that form the Stream ID can take values
>   between 3 and 65599. Some values have special meaning like 1 that
>   stands for an extended ID format, in which case there will be 2 bytes
>   following that. A value of 2 is for low level messages such as Ping
>   and Set Client Bandwidth.

Open-source RTMP client FLAZR also uses this parameter (under the name of 'channelId'), and from its sources looks like all RTMP messages to be decoded by RtmpDecoder class should be split by streamId and processed differently.

A question is : what is streamId?

It is not the classical streamId (or better say 'streamName'), used by Wowza server. Its just a single integer.

May be, it is some index of audio or video packets sent? But why so many channels available? Do RTMP servers really send audio and video data in different RTMP messages?
Or, may be, this is an index of streams current client is subscribed to?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience any connected RTMP client can work with many streams simultaneously 
(e.g. publish one stream and play other X streams)

So i guess that's the reason why stream Ids were invented.
Streamnames are longer than single integer, you understand :)